# canvas draw bitmap crash on Android 10 but not on Android 8

Tags: android, kotlin, android-10.0

I used canvas to draw bitmap and I used two version of android 8 and 10 to test. Somehow android 10 crash and I just dont seems to understand this error message:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: software rendering doesnot support hardware bitmaps**

Below is my code. The crash is on the this line:  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0F, 0F, null)

```
 private fun DrawRectTextAndBitmap()
    {

        val strOwnerName: String = "Owner: " + tvOwnerName.text.toString()
        val strCtcName:String = "Contact : " + tvCtcPersonName.text.toString()
        val strCtcMobileNo:String ="Mobile : " + tvCtcPersonMobile.text.toString()
        val strAddr1 : String ="Drug Allergy : " + tvAddr1.text.toString()
        val strAddr2: String = "Food Allergy : " + tvAddr2.text.toString()
   

          val bitmap1 = (imgResult.getDrawable() as BitmapDrawable).getBitmap()

          var h = bitmap1.height
          var w = bitmap1.width
        
          val newbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
          
          val canvas = Canvas(newbitmap)

          //-- draw background color

          canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN)
  
          
          //-- draw bitmap onto Canvas:

          canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0F, 0F, null)


          //-- create paint-based color

          val paint = Paint()
          paint.isAntiAlias()
          paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.royalblue))
          paint.alpha = 126
        
          val strDisplayAllText: String = strOwnerName
        
          val paintText = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
          paintText.setTextSize(rectTextSize)
          paintText.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.Lightgray))
          paintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL)

           val color1 = Color.parseColor("#f5f5f5")
            paintText.setColor(color1)
            paintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL)

          //-- Draw the Rectangle

          if (h > w ) {

              val rectangle = Rect(10, rectPortrait_StartPoint, rectPortrait_H, rectPortrait_W)

              canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint)

          } else {

              val rectangle = Rect(10, rectLandscape_StartPoint, rectLandscape_H, rectLandscape_W)
            
              canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint)
          }

         
          val rectText = Rect()
          paintText.getTextBounds(strOwnerName, 0, strDisplayAllText.length, rectText)

          if( h > w ) {

              canvas.drawText(strOwnerName, 20F, 830F, paintText)
              canvas.drawText(strCtcName, 20F, 890F, paintText)
              canvas.drawText(strCtcMobileNo, 20F, 950F, paintText)
              canvas.drawText(strAddr1, 20F, 1010F, paintText)
              canvas.drawText(strAddr2, 20F, 1110F, paintText)

              val density = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density
              imgResult.layoutParams.height = 240 * density.toInt()
              imgResult.layoutParams.width = 180 * density.toInt()
              imgResult.requestLayout()

          }else{

              //--landscape
            
              canvas.drawText(strOwnerName, 20F, 560F, paintText)
              canvas.drawText(strCtcName, 20F, 620F, paintText)
              canvas.drawText(strCtcMobileNo, 20F, 680F, paintText)
              canvas.drawText(strAddr1, 20F, 740F, paintText)
              canvas.drawText(strAddr2, 20F, 870F, paintText)

              val density = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density
              imgResult.layoutParams.width = 200 * density.toInt()
              imgResult.layoutParams.height = 200 * density.toInt()
              imgResult.requestLayout()
          }

          runOnUiThread {

              imgResult.setImageBitmap(newbitmap)
          }

         
      }
```

Update: I added the following

```
 1)  in manifest 

I added :

 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

 </application>


2 ) in code , I modified for the ImageView 

      imgResult.setImageBitmap(newbitmap)
     imgResult.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Comment: You did not google: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: software rendering doesnot support hardware bitmaps

Comment: it is hard to find for this android 10. The closet I found adding this : allowHardware(false) to your request. But I have no clue as there is not explanation:https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/159   other say use PixelCopy()

Answer (score 0):

from Canvas class:

```
private void throwIfHwBitmapInSwMode(Bitmap bitmap) {
   if (!isHardwareAccelerated() && bitmap.getConfig() == Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE) {
      onHwBitmapInSwMode();
   }
}
```

therefore make bitmap with config software, or enable hardware acceleration

Comment: You mean I just add this code somewhere in my activity ?  for kotlin, private fun throwIfHwBitmapInSwMode(bitmap:Bitmap) {
  if (!isHardwareAccelerated() && bitmap.getConfig() === Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE)
  {
    onHwBitmapInSwMode()
  }
}

Comment: No this code is called from sdk Canvas class, i just shown it to you

Comment: so this is for canvas class but I cannot change it?  for my problem, do you have solution ?

Comment: i wrote "therefore make bitmap with config software, or enable hardware acceleration"

Answer (score 0):

You should disable hardware acceleration by this tag `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`, it can be use in `Application` and `Activity`;

Or you can use this method for one particular `View` like

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Comment: When Apply this android:hardwareAccelerated ="false" in Manifest, will it affect other android version < 10?  Where in my code I can use view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE-SOFTWARE, null) ?? Thanks

Comment: you mean I do this: imgResult.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Comment: not working. adding android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in manidest, it will crash when I select photo in Gallery.  Take out this android:hardwareAccelerated="false", and add  this imgResult.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null) will not work., it crashes too. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: Aren't you writing a custom view? I mean you just use `setLayerType` on this view, like ```this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)```

Comment: Ykh  would appreciate if you can point out where I should add the changes you mentioned. See my Update,did I do it correctly? The above update will crash. This bug is really disturbing. It only crash for android 10. Thanks